# return struct from a function and memory allocation

Tags: c++, c

Lets consider such example:

```
typedef struct {
  int hours;
  int minutes;
  int seconds; 
} Time;

Time createTime() {
    Time time;
    time.hours = ....
    time.hours = ....
    time.hours = ....
    return time
}

void doSomething(){

    while(true){
        Time newTime = createTime(); 
        // do something with time....
    }
}
```

I have few questions about memory allocation

1. Why method `createTime()` does not return NULL? The `#time` is a local variable so it should be destroyed when method goes out of scope.
2. Inside method `doSomething()` I am calling `createTime()` multiple times, will this create memory leak?

Comment: i think for struct access specifier by default is global.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`createTime` cannot do `return NULL;` - it returns a `Time`.

Functions return by value in C and C++. This means that when you write `return time;`, there is a temporary object created called *the return value*. This is copied from the expression you return. In C this is member-wise copy, in C++ it uses the copy-constructor. So the sequence of events for the code `Time newTime = createTime();` is:

1. `time` inside `createTime()` is created and populated
2. The *return value* is created, and has its values copied from `time`
3. `time` is destroyed
4. `newTime` is created, with the *return value* used as initializer.
5. The *return value* is destroyed

Now this is in principle a lot of copying and destroying, but the compiler is permitted to optimize it (in both C and C++) so that the end result is that `createTime` can construct `time` directly into the memory space of `newTime`, with no temporaries needed. In practice you may find various levels of optimization applied.

NB. In C++11 replace *copy* with *copy or move* in the above.

Answer (score 6):

You don't return a pointer or reference, you return *by value* which means that the structure is *copied*. There's no dynamic memory allocation, it's all handled by the compiler at compilation-time, and since there's no dynamic allocation there's no chance of memory leaks.

There's one drawback to this, and that is that you can't return `NULL` to indicate that there's nothing to return. You must always return a valid structure.

Answer (score 3):

By saying `return time;` [with the `;`], you're returning the *value*, not the address, and collecting that return value into the variable in the caller. The return value is simply copied into `newTime`.

This is perfectly valid. There is no dynamic memory usage. There is no memory leak in this context.

Next, `createTime()` cannot return `NULL`, as the return type is specified as of type `Time`. It has to return a valid structure variable of type `Time`. Moreover, `NULL` is applicable for pointer types. However, you can return a structure with all the members initialized as `-1` [based on your structure definition, members are being `int`] to report some failure, if you wish.